LAST_N_DAYS:30 in SOQL vs. Last 30 Days In Reports
I noticed something strange today when I queried some opportunities via SOQL and via a report.  For the last 30 days, the Salesforce report includes 2024-11-14 to 2024-12-13 which equals 30 days (including today). If I do the same query in SOQL using CloseDate = LAST_N_DAYS:30, it starts on 2024-11-13, which equals 31 days (including today). Why is that?
Or, if I go back to the end of November and query for the last 30 days I will get the whole month via a report while via SOQL I will also get the last day of October. I would expect the last 30 days to include exactly 30 days as the report does. But the SOQL statement gives me 31 days. I don't get it.
Surely there's an explanation I can't find, but it's very odd if you just try to match your report to an SOQL statement or vice versa. Can anybody shine some light on this? I couldn't find anything related to this.

Running user timezone?

I do both with the same user.

Just to be 100 % sure I opened the report, then opened a developer console from there and executed my query with the same 30-day filter. The 1-day-difference is still there.

Exactly how did you apply the LAST_N_DAYS:30 in the SOQL? What operator did you use? Have you reviewed the documentation?

Great question. I read the documentation before and found it very confusing as the explanation for 90 days specifically says that it will return 91 days, so 30 days will also return one additional day. I just don't understand why and find it very counterintuitive.

I also added the exact filter I used in the SOQL query - CloseDate = LAST_N_DAYS:30.

I don't understand Salesforce's reasoning for n + 1 days either, but it does seem like the report filter is not following that rule.  Have you opened a case with Salesforce?  I know you're using the same user for both, but do you receive different results (report vs SOQL) at different times of day?  That would be crazy ...  Out of curiosity, what is the user's timezone?

CET - but it's a great idea to try this with different times of day, just to be sure. I'll try and report back.
